# visual studio 2010 c# simple compile help

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Hey I developed a small application and would like to compile it, however it comes with loads of extra stuff I dont want. All I want is a stand alone .exe file but instead I am getting pdb vshost.exe files etc. Is there anyway to get rid of these as I just want 1 .exe

Answer (score 1):

Just copy/paste the exe file out. VS uses those files internally, and one is full of debugging symbols. Your going to want it if you plan on stepping into the code.

Answer (score 0):

All these ''extra stuff'' is not required to run your ''small application''. You can verify that by copying the .exe file to a location where it will be standing alone indeed.

If it is not standing alone, as you say in the comment below: perhaps part of your code does compile to .dll, or you reference external dlls? Could you supply a list of filenames of files that are created?

Comment: I do that and it crashes when I try to open it

Comment: Perhaps part of your code does compile to .dll, or you reference external dlls?

Comment: im using System.IO all the rest are default.

Comment: And it runs fine when in the same directory as ''extra stuff''? Could you supply a list of filenames of files that are created in this directory?

Comment: the .application .manifest, .pdb, .vshost.application ,vshost.exe, vshost.exe.manifest

Comment: From the presence of the .application file I conclude you must be using ClickOnce to deploy your app -- I have no experience in doing that, there are only two things that come to my mind: 1. you can try disabling it in "signing" section of process properties; 2. it is some obscure problem in your app/vs/computer. If it helps anyhow please mark as answered and I'll put above in the answer -- otherwise, I'm afraid I cannot help you.